# Need to take price of parent to child item when child item do not have price

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to import item price from my database. And for some item only parent item has price and child is not exist in tarif table, in that case I tried to take the price from parent to child. And for some item even parent don't have price, in that case in my export in price field "`NULL`" is there.

My Query:
`GA_ARTICLE` is the item code, which the reference for my item and tarif table,`GA_CODEARTICLE` is same for both `CHILD` and PARENT item, `GF_DEVISE` is the field where my currency code is stored,

```
SELECT ga_article,
CASE 
    WHEN ga_article LIKE ga_Codearticle + '%X' THEN 
        SELECT TOP(1) GF_PRIXUNITAIRE 
        FROM tarif WHERE GF_ARTICLE LIKE ga_Codearticle + '%' AND GF_DEVISE='QAR') 
    END 
price 
FROM  Article
LEFT JOIN tarif 
    ON gf_article = GA_ARTICLE 
        AND GF_DEVISE = 'QAR'
```

Comment: If that query works then your not using MySQL but SQL Server (MSSQL), Because MySQL does not support `TOP()`

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix up your `LEFT JOIN` to already `SELECT` that `TOP 1` record, and then use the `CASE` statement to decide which field to display for price.

```
SELECT ga_article,
CASE 
    WHEN ga_article LIKE ga_Codearticle + '%X' THEN 
        t.GF_PRIXUNITAIRE  
    WHEN otherCondition THEN otherField
    ELSE NULL --this is implied even if you leave it out
    END 
price 
FROM  Article
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM tarif 
    WHERE gf_article = GA_ARTICLE 
        AND GF_DEVISE = 'QAR') t
```